# doubts about options in a tcp connection

Tags: tcp, log-files

in a log i have the following legend:

```
IN=enp4s0 OUT=enp2s0 MAC=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:08:00:XX:XX:XX:XX:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.45 DST=13.226.38.81 LEN=240 TOS=00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=260 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=49271 DPT=443 SEQ=1360142614 ACK=140365104 WINDOW=16450 ACK PSH URGP=0 MARK=0
```

There are some things that I know what they mean, but not others. The ones that I don't know what they mean and I would like to be clarified are:

```
LEN=240
TOS=00
PREC=0x00
ID=260
DF
SEQ=1360142614
WINDOW=16450
URGP=0
```

Thanks in advanced

Comment: _[RFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793)_ has the definitions and explanations for each field in a TCP header, although you seem to be looking at some fields of the IPv4 header encapsulating the TCP segment, and those are defined and explained in _[RFC 791, Internet Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc791)_

Comment: I can't find in the documents "WINDOW" and "URGP"

Comment: I do not think you looked very hard. Section 3 (pg. 15) of RFC 793 defines both the window and the urgent pointer, as well as the other TCP header fields.

Comment: mmm URGP = Urgent Pointer. Thk